# Cant loop through result set over two different methods

Tags: php

I have ran in to a pickle with using a while loop to iterate over a result set.

I execute a query, and pass into a class, storing it as a private variable.

Then I use two separate methods to do a while loop over the result set.

The first method works, the second doesn't.

Here's some code to show example.

```
<?php

class DataFlow {

    private $resultSet;

    function __construct($results) {
        $this->resultSet = $results;
    }

    function method1() {
        while ($rows = CDB::GetAssoc($this->resultSet)) {
            // works here
            echo $rows;
        }
    }

    function method2() {
        while ($rows = CDB::GetAssoc($this->resultSet)) {
            // doesn't work here 
            echo $rows;
        }
    }

}

$sqlQuery = "....";
$results = CDB::ExecuteQuery($sql);
$dataFlow = new DataFlow($results);

echo $dataflow->method1(); // Works
echo $dataflow->method2(); // Doesn't work.
?>
```

**Now if I edit this to include the query execution locally.. it works**

```
<?php

class DataFlow {

    private $resultSet;

    function __construct($results) {
        $this->resultSet = $results;
    }

    function method1() {
        while ($rows = CDB::GetAssoc($this->resultSet)) {
            // works here
            echo $rows;
        }
    }

    function method2() {
        $sqlQuery = "....";
        $results = CDB::ExecuteQuery($sql);

        while ($rows = CDB::GetAssoc($results)) {
            // now works here 
            echo $rows;
        }
    }

}

$sqlQuery = "....";
$results = CDB::ExecuteQuery($sql);
$dataFlow = new DataFlow($results);

echo $dataflow->method1(); // Works
echo $dataflow->method2(); // Works
?>
```

I can't seem to figure out why I can't use a result set twice in the same class. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

reading results from a database query involves iterating over some kind of a cursor going through the result rows. Depending on your database class, you might be able to reset this cursor to loop over the results several times if needed. If not, then you would have to perform the query again.

Comment: Ah, right, doesn't seem to be a method that resets it the beginning again. Thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I understand, `$results` is a resource, so X number of rows, fetch_assoc($results) will return one row from the resource, or NULL when there are no more rows.

So, at some point, `$row` will evaluate as false (as there are no more rows to return) which will end the while loop.

and the resource result that you pass to this function can be thought of as being passed by reference because a resource is simply a pointer to a memory location.

Because of this, you can not loop through a resource result twice in the same script before resetting the pointer back to the start position.